# AES subkey calculation not working for subkeys beyond 0 and 1

Tags: encryption, aes, keys

How should I generate the remaining keys when performing subkey generation in AES encryption? I generated keys 0 and 1 first, but the other keys I generated later were wrongly generated, so what steps should I do to generate the rest?
I know the steps of shifting rows and mixing columns but I don't know what to use when.

***This is Key 0:***
[image]

***This is Key 1:***
[image]

***These are the rest of the keys, and I don't know how they were generated exactly:***
[image]

Comment: Which sources did you consult for this, and what confused you about the subkey generation?

Comment: i don't know the exact source of the problem, i am confused about how did KEY2 ->KEY9 got generated

Comment: Assuming you're doing AES-128, you use the same mapping you used to transform KEY0->KEY1 to do KEY1->KEY2; the only change is that you use the next entry in the rcon table.

Comment: yes it's a 128 bit, i did as you said but the first element was = DA not 6F. I took the first column in KEY1 and XORE'D it with the subByte of the last column of KEY1 and then XORE'D it with the second column in the RCON tabel, so i did this [76 XOR AE XOR 02], [86 XOR 4B XOR 00], [59 XOR 4B XOR 00], [8A XOR 1B XOR 00] is that right?

Comment: https://youtu.be/nC0mjaUZd8w, this is the link of the video, this is the slideshow link, https://www.slideshare.net/PorushMarwaha/aes-encryption